# How to sort the items in only one key-value list within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a dictionary (will make up entries)

```
mystuff = {'candy': 10, 'purse' : ['phone', 'gum', 'bracelet'],'kit': ['bandages', 'tape']}
```

I only want to sort the items in the 'purse' key by alphabetical order. How would I do this without changing the order of everything else?

I expect the output to be

```
mystuff = {'candy': 10,'purse' : ['bracelet', 'gum', 'phone'],'kit' : ['bandages', 'tape']}
```

Comment: `mystuff['purse'].sort()`

Comment: lists are mutable to sorting the reference of the value that the dict access returns is enough like elomat comment above suggests. This is super basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you could just do `my_candy['purse'].sort()` in place. But that would mutate the existing data.

You could also use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to avoid mutation of the existing data, like this:

```
def new_value(key, value):
    return sorted(value) if key == 'purse' else value


transformed = {
    key: new_value(key, value)
    for key, value
    in mystuff.items()
}
```